# Upgrade Commerce Kickstart 1 site with drush

Tags: drush, commerce

From http://www.drupalcommerce.org/blog/9072/updating-commerce-kickstart-2 I learned that it's possible to upgrade a CK2 site using drush.

Is it possible to do a minor upgrade od CK1 using `drush dl --select commerce_kickstart` and selecting the proper version? I tried and failed.

Comment: What's your version of drush? drush --version

Comment: Drush Version   :  6.1.0

Answer (score -1):

According to this page http://www.drupalcommerce.org/commerce-kickstart-2/install you should use Drush 8.x-6.x for an upgrade.

Comment: That's just for Drupal 8, I suppose, and for CK2 anyhow?

Comment: Sorry misread, just tried to do an upgrade from 7.x-2.10 to 7.x-2.12 with --select and it indeed failed because it can't find the /tmp/drush_tmp directory. Perhaps a permission issue?

Comment: Exactly the result I had. Doing a 'sudo drush' did not help, though, so I doubt that be the question of permissions